# linux command found but not found when using sudo

Tags: linux, centos, bash, sudo

I am trying to run a python3 install like this:

```
pip3 install django
```

I get the error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytz'

I then try:

```
sudo pip3 install django
```

I get the error:

> sudo: pip3: command not found

Here is what my $PATH looks like:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
```

How can I get sudo access to pip3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I issued the django install this way:

```
pip3 install --user django
```

This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Sudo is not using the same `PATH` as your current user for security reasons. In `/etc/sudoers` there is an option **`secure_path`** which specifies the path used when running commands with sudo.
Mine looks like this:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

From the sudo manpage:

> ```
>  secure_path   Path used for every command run from sudo.  If you don't trust the people running sudo to have a sane PATH environment
>                variable you may want to use this.  Another use is if you want to have the “root path” be separate from the “user path”.
>                Users in the group specified by the exempt_group option are not affected by secure_path.  This option is not set by
>                default.
> ```

The `pip3` command is probably not in the path defined by the `sudoers` file. You can either add the path to the **`secure_path`** or provide the full path to the `pip3` command like this:

```
sudo /path/to/pip3 install django
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that sudo is not preserving your $PATH variable upon use. Try using the full path to the pip3 binary in the command, for example: `sudo /path/to/pip3 install django`. If you're unsure of the full path, do `which pip3`.

Comment: which pip3 outputs:  /usr/local/bin/pip3 .  The $PATH variable looks good as well:  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin

Comment: does `sudo echo $PATH` produce anything different? Did you try the command with the full path to pip3? Any difference in results?

Comment: sudo outputs the same:  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin

Answer (score 0):

You can always do:

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" pip3 install django
```

As it mentioned in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83194/176665).